# Is there a term for total money owed to you?

Tags: terminology, assets

Is there a word, in finance, for the total amount of money owed to you? That is, for money you "have" but you don't have yet.

For example, if I have $10k in the bank, and a total of $20k open invoices out to multiple clients that have not paid yet, I sort of have $30k, but not really. Is there a word for that $20k owed? Is there a different word for that $30k "hypothetical" total?

If it matters, let's say I am virtually 100% positive that I will receive that money owed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a word for that $20k owed?

Trade Receivables, Accounts Receivables, or just Receivables

> Is there a different word for that $30k "hypothetical" total?

Current Assets (Includes Inventory and other short term assets)

Comment: Ah, so, [looking that up](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/012815/what-difference-between-fixed-asset-and-current-asset.asp) would the $10k I already have be... "Fixed Assets"?

Comment: No. Fixed assets are things that cannot easily turn into cash, such as Property, Plant, and Equipment.